# (bash) grep -i not making search case insensitive for input files

Tags: grep

I am trying to search inside a folder containing several files. The name of the files is written in upper case with a .sub extension in lower case:

---

AAA.sub

BBB.sub

CCC.sub

DDD.sub

---

I am searching a pattern trough those file using grep, however i would like to only use lower case letter for the input files.

In the man page for grep it is written:

> -i, --ignore-case
>                 Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the **input files**.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)

So, if i understood properly:

> grep -i subckt /schematics/aaa

and

> grep -i subckt /schematics/AAA

Are supposed to both be able to search a pattern "subckt" in the file "aaa" regardless of its case (AAA or aaa) and if two files named aaa and AAA are present at the same time in the foler, i expect grep to search trough both of them.

However when i try my search with the 1st instruction (lower case) it does not work, giving me "no such file or directory" message.
When i try to search with the 2nd instruction (upper case) it works properly.

I obviously understood something wrong about how the -i option with grep, can anyone give me an answer regarding this matter?

Is it possible to be case insensitive with the input files when using grep?

EDIT:
My question was lacking details, even tough i have found the answer to my problem i will add the details in case someone else stumbles upon this:

I have one file that contains a list of each file name i want to grep. My list looks like this:

aaa  capacitor C_0

bbb  capacitor C_0

ccc  resistor  R_in

...

The grep is done inside a perl script, the perl script parses the list file and gets the name of each individual file name (aaa bbb ccc) inside a while loop.
However the name inside the list file is written in lower case whereas the name of the files i want to grep is written in upper case.

This is why i wanted to have the input file search to be case insensitive so that i could directly do a `grep -i subck aaa` and it would search inside the file 'AAA'

However, since the grep is launched from a perl script, and since it is apparently not possible to have grep behave like that, i used the uc() function of perl to convert aaa to AAA and do my grep with it. (see my answer below)

Comment: Are you on mac by any chance? There is a known bug in an early build of grep that Mac OS X is using. You can try to update your version of grep using homebrew!

Comment: No it's a red hat Linux worksation

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to search the files in a directory, or do you have a list of files (perhaps stored in a file) that you want to grep, or do you want to grep the contents of the files?

Comment: I must agree my question was perhaps lacking some details: *editing atm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-i` affects how the contents are searched, not the name of the files.

When the man page says "Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files." that really means that case is ignored in the pattern ( searching for AAA and aaa are equivalent) and the contents of the input files (a line would match if it includes "AAA" or "aaa" or even "AaA")

I think you want to either list all the filenames on the command line, or find a glob (i.e. wildcard) that matches all the filenames:

```
grep -i subckt *.sub
```

In Unix/Linux shells (bash, zsh, and so on) "*" is processed by the shell (bash) not the command (grep).  The command receives the list of files and actually can't tell the difference between whether a user typed "grep foo *" and "grep foo file1 file2 file3" (if the directory includes those 3 files)

Comment: Ok i see.
Using grep to look trough all the files at once is not what i want to do tough, i specifically want to search through each file one by one.
It seems that even tough i am reluctant to do it, i am bound to force to use upper case for the file path.

Thanks tough

P.S: i think the explanation for the grep man page is a bit ambiguous then. Is there a way to report such kind of things? it would be nice i think :) .

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command

find . -iname aaa.sub | grep -rn subckt

find with -iname option will list out files ignoring their case. In the above case find . -iname will list out both aaa.sub & AAA.sub. The output is piped to the grep command.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to circumvent my problem by using the uc (upper case) function of perl to convert the input files for the grep function into upper case.

The grep command was launched from a perl script in the first place:
`grep -i subckt /schematics/aaa`
So, i just did that in my perl script:

$tmp=aaa

$tmp=uc($tmp)

`grep -i subckt /schematics/$tmp`

Now, the "aaa" name is just an example. In the perl script it is recovered from another parsed file that is written in lower case.

Thanks for the answers tough.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` uses the filenames as they are listed on the command line.  The `-i` option affects the contents of the files, not the names of the files.

You can use `find` to select filenames to be searched.  The `-iname` option lets you match files ignoring case.

```
grep subckt $(find /schematics -iname aaa.sub -print)
```

If you have many filenames, or those filenames include spaces or other characters that would confuse the shell, the safe and secure way to do this is using the `-print0` and `-0` options:

```
find /schematics -iname aaa.sub -print0 | xargs -r -0 grep -i subckt
```